# access owned by an association cakephp

Tags: php, associations, cakephp-3.x

It is the first time I post here, someone can help me here want to access the object will see my associacion I have within my controller to assign a value and this is stored in a specific field Here my code

```
// Controller Advertisements 

namespace App\Controller;
```

use Cake\Filesystem\Folder;
use Cake\Filesystem\File;

class AdvertisementsController extends AuthController{

```
public function publicadd() {
    $publicadd = $this->Advertisements->newEntity(null,['associated' => ['AdvertisementsImagenes' 
            => ['fieldList' => 'name_imagen']]]);
    if($this->request->is('post')){
        $publicadd = $this->Advertisements->patchEntity($publicadd,$this->request->data,['associated' => ['AdvertisementsImagenes' 
            => ['fieldList' => 'name_imagen']]]);
        if ($this->request->data['advertisements_imagenes']['name_imagen']['error']==0) {
            $publicadd->AdvertisementsImagenes->name_imagen = $this->request->data['advertisements_imagenes']['name_imagen']['name'];
            new Folder(WWW_ROOT . 'anuncios',true,0755);
            $image = new File($this->request->data['advertisements_imagenes']['name_imagen']['tmp_name']);
            $image->copy(WWW_ROOT . 'anuncios/'.$this->request->data['advertisements_imagenes']['name_imagen']['name']);

        }
        $publicadd->id_user = $this->Auth->user('id_user');
        if ($this->Advertisements->save($publicadd)) {
            $this->Flash->success('Anuncio Publicado');
            $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Home','action' => 'index']);
        }  else {
            $this->Flash->error('Error al Publicar');
        }
    }
    $this->set('advertisements',$publicadd);
}
```

}

//entity Advertisement

```
class Advertisement extends Entity{
protected $_accessible = [
    '*' => true,
    'id_advertisement' => false,
];
```

}

//entity Relation AdvertisementImagen

```
class AdvertisementImagen extends Entity{
protected $_accessible = [
    'name_imagen' => true,
    'id_advertisement' => false,

];
```

}

// Error
**Notice (8): Indirect modification of overloaded property App\Model\Entity\Advertisement::$AdvertisementsImagenes has no effect [APP/Controller\AdvertisementsController.php, line 25]**

// Context, Code

```
=> ['fieldList' => 'name_imagen']]]);
        if ($this->request->data['advertisements_imagenes']['name_imagen']['error']==0) {
            $publicadd->AdvertisementsImagenes->name_imagen = $this->request->data['advertisements_imagenes']['name_imagen']['name'];

$publicadd = object(App\Model\Entity\Advertisement) {

'id_categorie' => (int) 1,
'id_article' => (int) 1,
'id_article_size' => (int) 1,
'id_state_article' => (int) 1,
'title' => 'Pruebas  Mujer',
'price' => (float) 260,
'description' => 'Pruebas imagenes',
'advertisements_imagenes' => [
    (int) 0 => object(App\Model\Entity\AdvertisementImagen) {}
],
'[new]' => true,
'[accessible]' => [
    '*' => true
],
'[dirty]' => [
    'id_categorie' => true,
    'id_article' => true,
    'id_article_size' => true,
    'id_state_article' => true,
    'title' => true,
    'price' => true,
    'description' => true,
    'advertisements_imagenes' => true
],
'[original]' => [],
'[virtual]' => [],
'[errors]' => [],
'[invalid]' => [],
'[repository]' => 'Advertisements'
```

}

please help Thanks

Comment: You should explain your relationships, in any case try `$publicadd->advertisements_imagenes-> etc...` you should use lower case underscored when you are accessing an entity (or an array of entities) inside another entity. Instead use CamelCase when you are accessing a Model through another Model.

Comment: Please could you explain a little better not understand Thanks

Comment: simply not `$publicadd->AdvertisementsImagenes->` but `$publicadd->advertisements_imagenes` (or something similar as I don't now how to correctly pluralize your models and also I don't now the relationships between the models). Read [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html) about cake conventions. IN particular read about entity naming conventions

Comment: change it but still shows me this error `Warning (2): Attempt to assign property of non-object  => ['fieldList' => 'name_imagen']]]);
            if ($this->request->data['advertisements_imagenes']['name_imagen']['error']==0) {
                $publicadd->advertisements_imagenes->name_imagen = $this->request->data['advertisements_imagenes']['name_imagen']['name'];` I must be doing something wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix only change in my position controller and select the array

> $publicadd->advertisements_imagenes[0]->name_imagen = $this->request->data['advertisements_imagenes']['name_imagen']['name'];

```
public function publicadd() {
    $publicadd = $this->Advertisements->newEntity();
    if($this->request->is('post')){
        $publicadd = $this->Advertisements->patchEntity($publicadd,$this->request->data,['associated' => ['AdvertisementsImagenes' 
            => ['accessibleFields' => ['name_imagen'=>true]]]]);
        if ($this->request->data['advertisements_imagenes']['name_imagen']['error']==0) {
            $publicadd->advertisements_imagenes[0]->name_imagen = $this->request->data['advertisements_imagenes']['name_imagen']['name'];
            new Folder(WWW_ROOT . 'anuncios',true,0755);
            $image = new File($this->request->data['advertisements_imagenes']['name_imagen']['tmp_name']);
            $image->copy(WWW_ROOT . 'anuncios/'.$this->request->data['advertisements_imagenes']['name_imagen']['name']);
        }
        $publicadd->id_user = $this->Auth->user('id_user');
        if ($this->Advertisements->save($publicadd)) {
            $this->Flash->success('Anuncio Publicado');
            $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Home','action' => 'index']);
        }  else {
            $this->Flash->error('Error al Publicar');
        }
    }
    $this->set('advertisements',$publicadd);
    $query_categories = $this->Categories->find('list');
    $this->set('categories',$query_categories);
    $query_articles = $this->Articles->find('list');
    $this->set('articles',$query_articles);
    $query_sizes = $this->ArticlesSizes->find('list');
    $this->set('sizes',$query_sizes);
    $query_articles_states = $this->StatesArticles->find('list');
    $this->set('states',$query_articles_states);
}
```

Thank you